# How to show half of the string in listview in android

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I am taking a path from storage and put it in arraylist and showing in listview. I want to show only the moviename i.e Faltu not he encrypted how can i do it. Please Help

Firstly user download a movie in which i pass encrypted mac id with movie name.

[This is screenshot moviename with encrypted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCEW8.png)

GetDownloadMovieinList.class:

```
 private File yourDir;
ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder;
ListView lv;


 lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView_download);

 File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "/MoreData/closed");
 final ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(yourDir);



/* Dafault Adapter is used*/

if(FilesInFolder!=null) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.text_search1, FilesInFolder);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);




public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(File DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(String.valueOf(DirectoryPath));

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
            MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
```

DownloadMovie.class

```
 WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
    AndroidId = info.getMacAddress();
  String password = AndroidId;

    Log.d("MacPass",password+"");

    String passwordEnc = null;
    try {
        passwordEnc = AES.encrypt(password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
alphaAndDigits = movie_name_from_down_activity  +passwordEnc ;
if(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED==16) {
        File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File oldFile = new File(sdCardRoot, "/MoreData/closed/" + alphaAndDigits);
```

AES.class

```
public class AESencrp {




private static final String ALGO = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue =
        new byte[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',

                '7', '8', '9', '0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };


public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    //String encryptedValue = com.example.xpertech.aesencryption.Base64.encodeToString(encVal, com.example.xpertech.aesencryption.Base64.DEFAULT);
 //   String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

   // byte[] decordedValue = new  com.example.xpertech.aesencryption.Base64.Decoder(encryptedData, com.example.xpertech.aesencryption.Base64.NO_WRAP);
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);

   // byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);

    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    return key;
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Is there any rule of how encryption was generated?

Comment: no @StasMelnychenko ! its constant encrypted code Start from this "(" to" = "

Comment: @SumitKumar Post the relevant code. How are we supposed to figure out what's wrong if we don't see the encryption nor the populating of the `ListView`?

Comment: I don't see any "(" or "=" in your example. It's "9850124875852adsd"

Comment: updated again !!! in listview i get a movie name + mac address but i just want to show only movie name in display of listview !! thnx !!

Comment: itz done by using base adapter!!!!